# How can I use my .tpk file in with ArcGIS QT SDK?

Tags: qt, arcgis-runtime-sdk-qt

I am using developer edition of ArcGIS QT SDK. However I could not find any document about giving path of my .tpk file to the basemap class in the code. Need help people..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [sample code](https://developers.arcgis.com/qt/latest/cpp/sample-code/local-server-geoprocessing/) makes use of a TPK as a basemap. (LocalServerGeoprocessing.cpp)
It seems [TPKs are supported with LocalServer](https://developers.arcgis.com/qt/10-2/cpp/guide/local-server-package-support.htm).

```
  TileCache* tileCache = new TileCache(dataPath + "/tpk/RasterHillshade.tpk", this);
  m_tiledLayer = new ArcGISTiledLayer(tileCache, this);
  m_map->operationalLayers()->append(m_tiledLayer);
```

Additionally, there are a lot of samples on github, specifically [this one](https://github.com/Esri/arcgis-runtime-samples-qt/tree/a7e0b58bd0932fe20f08793b6318c81a02c196b7/ArcGISRuntimeSDKQt_CppSamples/Maps/GenerateOfflineMapLocalBasemap) makes use of TPKs.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need Local Server to display a tile package (.tpk). You DO, however, need Local Server to display a *map package (.mpk*).

The previous answer will add the tile package to your operational layers, not the basemap. To use a local .tpk as your basemap:

```
TileCache* tileCache = new TileCache(fileLocation, this);
ArcGISTiledLayer* tiledLayer = new ArcGISTiledLayer(tileCache, this);
Basemap* basemap = new Basemap(tiledLayer, this);
m_map = new Map(basemap, this);
m_mapView->setMap(m_map);
```